# a good beginner's graphic tutorial?

Tags: java, android, graphics, image-processing, transformation

i was wondering if any of you image processing gurus know a good tutorial to get me going from scratch with graphics and image processing in java? The type of things i'd like to learn is matrix transformatons, using a src image and applying a matrix to the dst image. Thanks in advance Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-1998/jw-09-media.html) quite a nice introduction tutorial in Image Processing with Java. It has theory, which is transferable to Android (and other platforms).
Once you know some of the theory, [this tutorial](https://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/Working-with-Images-in-Googles-Android-3748281.htm) explains how to manipulate images and pixels on Android.

There are some existing libraries which you can use as well such as a [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/). This will abstract away some of the lower level details.

Comment: ok cool i'll have a look now. thanks